# Is it safe to use boost provided shared memory and rt_signal (provided in linux) for realtime system?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, real-time, preempt-rt

I am currently working with building realtime IPC system.

I am trying to build a realtime system free of all undeterministic components.

I try to setup IPC based on shared memory model.

Is it safe to use managed_shared_memory from boost library to minimize unpredictable latency? or should I use mmap() for memory sharing?

Also Is rt_signal which has channel from SIGRTMIN to SIGRTMAX safe to use?

Thanks! By the way I am using them on preempt-rt patched linux kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe to use `managed_shared_memory` from boost library to minimize unpredictable latency? or should I use `mmap()` for memory sharing?

Manipulating process address space mapping with [`mmap` or `brk` is an expensive operation](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=95496636207616&w=2), so you'd want to minimize the number of times you use `mmap`. `mmap` is one source of unpredictable latency.

`managed_shared_memory` uses `mmap` and provides extra functionality on top of that, which you'd need to implement yourself when using `mmap`.

It probably doesn't matter for performance which one you use since `mmap` cost is going to dominate.

> Also Is `rt_signal` which has channel from `SIGRTMIN` to `SIGRTMAX` safe to use?

Signals may not be the best choice for IPC because the POSIX signal interfaces are prone to race conditions: process ids get reused so that `pid` argument may refer to a totally different process by the time you call `sigqueue`.

Signals only support directed communication, no broadcast. There is also a system-wide limit on the number of queued real-time signals.

And the APIs to handle signals aren't convenient, but that recently changed with the introduction of [`signalfd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) and [`pidfd_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_open.2.html).

---

A relatively simple and robust message-based shared-memory IPC is a message ring-buffer in shared memory along with a shared memory mutex and condition variable.

Boost Interprocess library provides `interprocess_mutex` and `interprocess_condition` and for ring-buffer you can use `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue` with a fixed-size.

---

> By the way I am using them on preempt-rt patched linux kernel.

You should watch [Kernel Recipes 2016 - Who needs a Real-Time Operating System (Not You!) - Steven Rostedt](https://youtu.be/4UY7hQjEW34). Real-time basically means slow but with guaranteed dead-lines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a further question. I am looking for a asynchronous event signal that could be used for realtime system. For example, process A updates a piece of shared memory with fresh data, then notifies process B which was waiting for the piece of shared memory that now process B can use it. What would be the fastest (average latency wise) and deadline guaranteeing mechanism for it assuming preempt rt is being used. it would be great if max latency is always less than 30us.

Comment: @BabySWEngineer If you just update a shared structure, then you don't need a queue. The process mutex and condition variable allow you to notify the waiters. It takes roughly 1us to wake up a waiting process using condition variable.